# How to avoid multiple OR statement bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

I have GUI check list for parameters to use grep search. When you check the list - this parameter should show up in grep control option.

For example:

```
w=TRUE or FALSE
s=TRUE or FALSE
N=TRUE or FALSE
L=TRUE or FALSE
```

And I would like to use all combination of check list selection something like:

```
if [ "$w" == TRUE ]; then

grep -w searsch_pattern INFILE


elif [ "$w" == TRUE ] && [ "$s" == TRUE ];then

grep -w -s searsch_pattern INFILE

....

fi
```

My question is if possible to avoid write all combination elif statement and found some more elegant solution.

PS: I want to use more then four output control parameters in grep search.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: sorry after equal should be quotes - if [ "$w" == "TRUE" ] ... and so on..

Comment: Use `=` with `[`, or use `[[`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no, unless the effects of each flag are independent. You could try building up the arguments to `grep` in an array. For example:

```
grep_options=()
if [ $w == TRUE ]; then
    grep_options+=( -w  )
fi

if [[ $s == TRUE ]]; then
    grep_options+=(-s)
fi

# etc.

grep "${grep_options[@]}" search_pattern INFILE
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing so. There is a GREP_OPTIONS variable supported by `grep`. Using the same variable, lowercased, which behaves differently leads to confusion imo.

Comment: It's not part of the POSIX standard, and learning that parameter names are case-sensitive is a rather important skill.

Comment: Learning that variables names should not just differ in their "caseness" is important as well. Why not calling them user_options or something like that?

Comment: Have another question. Why do you enforce putting the search_pattern right after the `-w` option? Is there a grep which requires that? At least `GNU` grep whith `POSIXLY_CORRECT` being set does not require that.

Comment: Some operating systems require all options to precede the positional arguments. It's not something controlled by the shell or `grep`. Which my code doesn't enforce, either. Fixing.

Comment: Ah ok, was just wondering.. At the end it looks good and satisfies the OP's requirements. +1

Answer (score 1):

For single options as in your example, you can try :

```
w=TRUE 
s=TRUE
N=FALSE
L=TRUE

for opt in w s N L; do
  [[ ${!opt} == "TRUE" ]] && options+=" -${opt}"
done

grep "${options}" searchpattern INFILE
```

Comment: You're assuming that each variable is just the name of a simple option. That might be a valid assumption, but there might be a variable `foo` which means, e.g., "add `-e foo[abc]` to the list of options".

Comment: And now you have a whitespace problem, which is why I used an array instead of a regular parameter.

Comment: @chepner Which whitespace problem ?

Comment: For instance, `options+=" -e 'regex with space'"`.

Comment: Can you explain ? I don't see where a regex with spaces is a problem.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the link. As the question was clearly not about parameter validation, i remove this part of my answer.